# Move labels into middle of pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I've got my pie chart working but I noticed that the text boxes for the actual chart doesn't seem to be working correctly. They are just clustered so I was wondering is there any way for me to move the labels into the middle where the white circle is and have the matching colour beside it or not?

```
crimeTypes = dict(crimeData["Crime type"].value_counts())

crimeType = []
totalAmount = []
numberOfCrimes = 14

for key in sorted(crimeTypes, key=crimeTypes.get, reverse=True):
    crimeType.append(key)
    totalAmount.append(crimeTypes.get(key))

crimeType_sample = crimeType[0:numberOfCrimes]
totalAmount_sample = totalAmount[0:numberOfCrimes]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(totalAmount_sample, labels=crimeType_sample, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.set_size_inches(10,10)
circle = plt.Circle(xy=(0,0), radius=0.75, facecolor='white')
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.show();
```

[image]

Comment: I'm gonna drop pandas from the title because it's a matplotlib issue, but nice question :)

Comment: No worries, sorry about that, wasn't too sure which thing I had to add!

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's a refreshing question from a new user. I have a feeling I know who can/will answer this (I can't) but if you can include data to make a repeatable example for them to test with, even better. Doesn't have to be your real data, just a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some sample data to reproduce your problem:

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = (['Burglary']*50 + ['Arson', 'Theft', 'Violence'] + ['Drugs']*10 + ['Other'] + 
        ['Shoplifting']*4 + ['Harassment']*17 + ['Murder', 'Vehicle Crime']*3 + 
        ['Some other Crimes']*12 + ['Even More Crime', 'And Crime', 'And More Crime']*10)
crimeData = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Crime type'])
```

Which will result in this plot:

[image]

---

### Use a legend

Do not plot the percentages or labels when you plot, and then create a legend which is placed off to the side:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.pie(totalAmount_sample, shadow=False, startangle=90)  # No labels or %s
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.set_size_inches(5,5)
circle = plt.Circle(xy=(0,0), radius=0.75, facecolor='white')
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

plt.legend(labels=[f'{x} {np.round(y/sum(totalAmount_sample)*100,1)}%' for x,y in crimeTypes.items()], 
           bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))

plt.show();
```

[image]

### Rotate the labels:

Create your labels and use `rotatelabels=True`. Though this may still appear cramped in many cases.

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

labels=[f'{x} {np.round(y/sum(totalAmount_sample)*100,1)}%' for x,y in crimeTypes.items()]
ax1.pie(totalAmount_sample, labels=labels, shadow=False, startangle=90,
        rotatelabels=True)  # No %

ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.set_size_inches(7,7)
circle = plt.Circle(xy=(0,0), radius=0.75, facecolor='white')
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

plt.show();
```

[image]